# With Symfony form, how to change ChoiceType values according to another value?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

With Symfony 7, i have a form.
Here a part of this form :

```
            ->add('primary', EntityType::class, [
                "label" => "Main menu",
                'class' => PrimaryNavItems::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                "mapped" => false,
            ])
            ->add('parent_nav', EntityType::class, [
                "label" => "Item",
                'class' => SecondaryNavItems::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title',
            ])
```

I want to display **parent_nav** values (dynamicaly) according to the **primary** value selected.
This is possible ?

I already have a relation in MySQL between **PrimaryNavItems** and **SecondaryNavItems**.

Ive tried with :

```
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        $primary = $data['primary'] ?? null;

        dd($primary);
    });
```

But nothing appends when i change my primary value.

and with this way :

```
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        $primary = $data['primary'] ?? null;

        dd($primary);
    });
```

give to me the right value.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html
or
https://ux.symfony.com/demos/live-component/dependent-form-fields

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
$primary = $event->getForm()->get('primary')->getData();
```